# Inverse function to StringUtils.capitalize()

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

There is convenient method `StringUtils.capitalize()` in `apache-commons-lang` library. But I can not find pairwise inverse method for it, which will make first letter in word in lowercase. Does such method exists?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't agree with you: there are situations where it would be nice to have translation from "AbcAbc" to "abcAbc", for example, in code generation tasks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [`StringUtils.uncapitalize`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#uncapitalize(java.lang.String)):

> Uncapitalizes a String changing the first letter to title case as per `Character.toLowerCase(char)`. No other letters are changed.